# PowerShell Add AD users to AD group by UPN from CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0, import-csv

```
Import-CSV "C:\Temp\jacktest.csv" | Foreach-Object {
  $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UPN-eq '$($_.UPN)'"
  if( $aduser ) {
    Write-Output "Adding user $($aduser.SamAccountName) to groupname"
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity JackTest -Members $aduser
  } else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find user in AD with email address $($_.EmailAddress)"
  }
}
```

## I receive the following Error:

Transcript started, output file is C:\Temp\Add-ADUsers.log
Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:19 char:15

- ```
  $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UPN -eq '$UPN'" | Select-Object Sam ...
  ```
- ```
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: The code you've posted at the top appears to be correct, but the code you're actually running (as evident by the error message) is not - the error happens because `$UPN` doesn't have any value, so the filter string evaluates to `"UPN -eq ''"`. Once you fix that, it still won't work, because `UPN` is not the correct display name for the `userPrincipalName` attribute :)

Comment: Thanks, are you able to help me with the fix please?

Comment: Not without knowing what happens when you run the code. Please post the actual error you see (the error you've posted is clearly not produced by the code you've posted)

Comment: Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:2 char:13
+   $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UPN -eq '$($_.UPN)'"
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser


Thanks!

Comment: That's _also not_ the code you've posted (`"UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.UserPrincipalName)'"` vs `"UPN -eq '$($_.UPN)'"`). Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70681169/edit) with the exact code you're running along with the exact error messages it produces.

Comment: Code
Import-CSV "C:\Temp\jacktest.csv" -delimiter "`t" | Foreach-Object {
  $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UPN -eq '$($_.UPN)'"
  if( $aduser ) {
    Write-Output "Adding user $($aduser.SamAccountName) to groupname"
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity JackTest -Members $aduser
  } else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find user in AD with email address $($_.EmailAddress)"
  }
}

Comment: Error Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:2 char:13
+   $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UPN -eq '$($_.UPN)'"
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: [Please update your existing post instead of posting code in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70681169/edit) :)

Comment: Updated, apologies for the mix up!

Comment: No worries. The error (and likely the cause) is still the same though - `$_.UPN` resolves to an empty string, producing the invalid filter expression `UPN -eq ''`. Are you 100% sure the CSV file has a `UPN` column? Perhaps the header row is missing from the CSV? In any case: `UPN` needs to be changed to `UserPrincipalName` and `$_.UPN` needs to be changed to `$_.<actualColumnName>`.

Comment: I have made the advised changes. Changing UPN to UserPrincipalName. My .csv column header is also UserPrincipalName, 
I'm still getting the same error. Thanks!

Comment: You have changed your post back to `"UPN -eq '$UPN'"` which is wrong. The filter should test the AD attribute called `UserPrincipalName`, so if the column in your csv is `Whatever`, the filter should be `"UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.Whatever)'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is meant to help you troubleshoot your issue so we can understand what could be going wrong with your CSV.

Note, this code assumes that your CSV is comma delimited and the CSV has a column with name "UserPrincipalName".

```
$usersToAdd = foreach($line in Import-CSV "C:\Temp\jacktest.csv")
{
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line.UserPrincipalName))
    {
        Write-Warning 'Empty UserPrincialName Value:'
        Write-Warning $line
        continue
    }

    $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($line.UserPrincipalName)'"
    if(-not $aduser)
    {
        Write-Warning "$($line.UserPrincipalName) could not be found."
        continue
    }

    $aduser
}

if($usersToAdd)
{
    Write-Host 'The following users will be added to the Group'
    $usersToAdd.UserPrincialName
    try
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity JackTest -Members $usersToAdd
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @JackBrooks glad to hear it, so what was the problem with the csv? im curious now :D

Comment: The script works and adds the users to the specified AD group as intended. The progress part  does not list the users 
This part = 
Write-Host 'The following users will be added to the Group'
    $usersToAdd.UserPrincialName
    try

Answer (score 0):

check the csv file, it seems you are not using the default delimiter.
if so add parameter -delimiter to the import-csv cmdlet.
for example for Tab delimiter:

```
Import-CSV "C:\Temp\jacktest.csv" -delimiter "`t"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Still receiving the same error



Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:2 char:13
+   $aduser = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.UserPrinc ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
 
WARNING: Could not find user in AD with email address

Comment: but what is your delimiter? open the csv with notepad to see if it is tab or colon or semicolon...